# How can I search a file for a group of patterns and then return thenumbers of the lines that they are located in?

Tags: bash, logging, grep

I have a large syslog file (several gigabytes) that contains logs for around 1800 devices.

ex.

```
timestamp device1 devicelog
timestamp device2 devicelog
timestamp device3 devicelog
timestamp device1 devicelog
timestamp device1 devicelog
timestamp device2 devicelog
```

How can I go through the log file and return all of the line numbers that each device is located in? So for example I would have the following output:

```
device1: 1,4,5
device2: 2,6
device3: 3
```

One thought that came to mind was grep -c'ing the log file for each individual device name, but that would take an eternity with the size of the log file and the number of devices that I would be searching for. I briefly thought about removing the matched lines for a device after every grep, but I do not want to edit the log file, nor do I have much extra space on the server to make a copy of the file.

Is there a faster way of doing this? Awk came to mind but I'm not too savvy with it yet, so I'm not sure if it would be possible to use it for this purpose or not.

Comment: How big is your file? grep should handle quite large files quickly, I suggest timing it to see. Also  egrep is the more modern version of grep. You could use a Perl or Python script for more advanced searching, but I'm not sure if you need it at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
$ awk '{a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2]",":"")NR;} END{for (dev in a)print dev,a[dev];}' file
device1 1,4,5
device2 2,6
device3 3
```

#### How it works

- `a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2]",":"")NR`

  For every line in the file, we add the line number, `NR`, to array `a` under the key of the device name, `$2`.

  Before adding `NR`, we check to see If there already is one or more numbers stored in `a[$2]`.  If there is, then we add a comma before we add `NR`.
- `END{for (dev in a)print dev,a[dev];}`

  When we reach the end of the file, we print out the contents of array `a`.

Comment: nice one +1. could be `awk '{a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2]",":"")NR} END{for (dev in a)print dev,a[dev];}'`

Comment: @Kent Excellent.  I updated the answer with your version of the ternary statement.